# Build error after updating framework xcode8

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, ios-charts

I've just converted my app to Swift 3, and as part of this I have updated the well known "Charts" framework. All of my converted code is fine and building/testing well, so I have no concerns about that.

I have embedded the binary to use the framework after unlinking the old one, cleaned the project, built the project before trying to use any framework code, and cleared derived data.

> However I still get a "ChartViewDelegate" is not available, cannot
>   find swift declaration for this protocol.

This is odd to me, as the Charts module imports fine, and autocomplete recognised all member classes of the framework. Also, it doesn't seem to be an issue with the framework, as when implementing the framework on a "fresh" project, it works perfectly as expected.

I'm at a loss of what to try next, apart from rewriting an entire app into a fresh project where I know the framework works. The framework is an integral part of the app. Thanks!

EDIT: I have already tried cleaning/clearing derived data.

Comment: In the error, `chartviewdelegate` has no capitals. Typically protocols are CamelCased. It may be that you are trying to use `chartviewdelegate` when you mean to use `ChartViewDelegate`.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect that there are indeed capitals in ChartViewDelegate already, this is the correct form

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem recently with any frameworks I added to my project manually. I fixed this by totally removing the offending frameworks and then installing via cocoa pods.

Comment: Thanks Olivier, I'll try this tomorrow and report back